# How to call a function in controller from anther function? - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

1 - This is an example of the problem that I face...

```
class LeaderController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
      $person = Leader::all();

      return view('show');
   }

   public function store(Request $request)
   {
      //how to call the index function above from here?
   }
}
```

Comment: `return $this->index();`?

Comment: Is the index() function working as expected? $person is not passed to the view.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the answer you are looking for,
including passing `$person` to the view.

```
class LeaderController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
      $person = Leader::all();
      return view('show', ['person' => $person]);
   }

   public function store(Request $request)
   {
      // perform some stuff

      return $this->index();
   }
}
```